# Duplicate partitioning key performance impact in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, schema

I've read in some posts that having duplicate partitioning key can have a performance impact. I've two tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE "Test1" (               CREATE TABLE "Test2" (
  key text,                          key text,
  column1 text,                      name text,
  value text,                        age text,             
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)         ...
)                                    PRIMARY KEY (key, name,age)
                                     )
```

In Test1 **column1** will contain column name and **value** will contain its corresponding value.The main advantage of Test1 is that I can add any number of column/value pairs to it without altering the table by just providing same partitioning key each time.

Now my question is how will each of these table schema's impact the read/write performance if I've millions of rows and number of columns can be upto 50 in each row. How will it impact the compaction/repair time if I'm writing duplicate entries frequently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For efficient queries, you want to hit a parition (i.e. have the first key of your primary key in your query). Inside of your partition, each column is stored in sorted form by the respective clustering keys. Cassandra stores data as "map of sorted maps".

Your Test1 schema will allow you to fetch all columns for a key, or a specific column for a key. Each "entry" will be on a separate parition.

For Test2, you can query by key, (key and name), or (key, name and age). But you won't be able to get to the age for a key without also specifying the name (w/o adding a secondary index). For this schema too, each "entry" will be in its own partition.

Cross partition queries are more expensive than those that hit a single partition. If you're looking for simply key-value lookups, then either schema will suffice. I wouldn't be worried using either for 50 columns. The first will give you direct access to a particular column. The latter will give you access to the whole data for an entry.

What you should focus more on is which structure allows you to do the queries you want. The first won't be very useful for secondary indexes, but the second will, for example.